# Run sagemaker jupyter notebook using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have a "notebook instance" in aws sagemaker, this instance has many notebooks.

Is there any way to use aws cli (shell) to individually start the notebooks and check their current status (running, stopped, etc...)?

If not, what ways can I use to perform the above actions programmatically?

Comment: are you looking for something like: ```aws sagemaker list-notebook-instances``` and ```aws sagemaker start-notebook-instance``` ?

Comment: That only starts the instance itself, I want to run the notebooks inside the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the status of sagemaker notebook instance by using command

- $ aws sagemaker describe-notebook-instance --notebook-instance-name your_instance_name

which will return detail about instance.

To launch notebook from aws cli use the following command

- $ aws sagemaker create-presigned-notebook-instance-url --notebook-instance-name your_instance_name

The above command will return url of jupyter notebook, copy paste it in the browser.

For more help see

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-presigned-notebook-instance-url.html
and
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/howitworks-access-ws.html